# If $f(x)$ is increasing, and $g(x)$ is decreasing, $f(x)g(x)$ must be decreasing?

Tags: calculus

Can the multiplication of an increasing function, say $f(x)$, with a decreasing function in $x$, say $g(x)$, be increasing? If it is possible, can you give me an example please?

Constraint: $x > 0$

Comment: I am not ... :S

Comment: @Alex: I'm confused -- what does the $O(\cdot)$ notation have to do with the OP's question?

Comment: Yes x is continuous.

Answer (score 8):

Look at these cases

- $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\frac1x$
- $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\frac1{x^2}$

Comment: Or even, if you want them to be defined on $\mathbb{R}$, anything of the form $f\colon x\mapsto e^{2x}$ and $g_1\colon x\mapsto e^{-x}$, $g_2\colon x\mapsto e^{-3x}$.

Comment: I guess this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

No. Think on this functions defined for $x>0$:

- $f(x)=x^2$ is increasing
- $g(x)=1/x$ is decreasing

Then:

- $f(x)g(x)=(x^2)*(\frac{1}{x})=x$ that is increasing.